# Only last reading before the 1st of next month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Number field is the key but it can be modified several times a month (or not all all). Need to pull for last 6 complete month/year (Month_Year), only last reading before the 1st of next month.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like this?

```
select number, to_char(sysdate, 'Mon-YYYY') as month_year,
       max(reading) keep (dense_rank first order by modified_date_time desc) as reading
from t
group by number;
```

The most recent reading for each number along with the current date formatted as Mon-YYYY.

Comment: How do I get data for last 6 months with only last reading before the 1st of next month?

Comment: @user12573256 . . . (1) You would add `where modified_date_time < add_months(sysdate, -6)`, but that doesn't seem necessary.  (2) Your data has no future dates, so I see no need to prevent future dates.

Comment: I have these 18K plus "number" field that can be modified or not throughout day. I want to capture for each unit what the latest reading is for given month/year for last 6 months. For e.g., for number 1, say reading based on max modified datetime is null on Oct 2020, 200 on Nov 2020, null on dec 2020. I want to have column for Oct 2020, Nov 2020 and Dec 2020. Oct reading is null so want to pull latest reading from prior months when there is non null reading and put it under Oct 20 field for that unit, Nov 20would be 200 and Dec be 200